# How to extraxt immediate next row after the last observations within a group in R and rbind them to geather

Tags: r

My Data is as follows DF is ABC

```
Dialled_nbr Ringing_nbr  Phone_state  duration
111          NA                    
111          NA
111          NA
NA           NA          Active       60
NA           NA          Active       0
222          NA
222          NA
222          NA
NA           NA          Active       90
NA           NA          Active       0
NA           NA
NA           456
NA           456
NA           NA          Active       100

I want to extract the immediate next row of the data after the last observations within 
a group for **Dialled_nbr**.


Answer I want is 
Dialled_nbr Ringing_nbr  Phone_state  duration
NA           NA          Active       60
NA           NA          Active       90
```

I am new to R....Please help...

Comment: can you reformat your input?

Comment: I am not able to do it.....Ph_nbr is a colmn...which contains all these values

Comment: It is clearer for all readers like this, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace your `NA` with `0` since you are working with:

```
df <- data.frame(
Dialled_nbr=c(111,111,111,NA,NA,222,222,222,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
Ringing_nbr=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,456,456,NA),
Phone_state=c('','','','Active','Active','','','','Active','Active','','','','Active'),
duration=c('','','','60','0','','','','90','0','','','','100'))

df[is.na(df)]=0
vec = with(df, c(head(Dialled_nbr,1), head(Dialled_nbr,-1)))
df[df$Dialled_nbr!=vec & df$Dialled_nbr==0,]
#      Dialled_nbr Ringing_nbr Phone_state duration
#4           0           0      Active       60
#9           0           0      Active       90
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cryptic solution:

```
x = c(111,111,111,123456,222,222,222,67890);
x[c(T,x[2:length(x)] != x[1:(length(x)-1)]) & c(x[1:(length(x)-1)] != x[2:length(x)],T)];
```

It basically calculates a logical vector representing which elements are *not* equal to their immediately *preceding* element (passing the first element unconditionally), and then ANDing that with a logical vector representing which elements are *not* equal to their immediately *following* element (passing the last element unconditionally). Hence, the final logical vector you get represents which elements are not in a group of 2-or-more consecutive identical values. You then index the original vector with that logical vector to get your result.

Actually, upon re-reading your question, the above line may not be what you're looking for, because it would get any value that is not equal to either one of its adjacent elements, even if it's not preceded by a group of 2-or-more identical values (although your example data suggests that all isolated values will follow a 2-or-more group). This one might be more appropriate:

```
x = c(111,111,111,123456,222,222,222,67890);
group <- c(T,x[2:length(x)] == x[1:(length(x)-1)]) | c(x[1:(length(x)-1)] == x[2:length(x)],F);
x[!group & c(F,group[1:(length(group)-1)])];
```

This one constructs a logical vector of elements which *are* equal to *either* their preceding *or* their following element. Thus, the TRUE values are the group elements, and the FALSE values are the non-group elements. You can then get all non-group elements by inverting the group vector, and then AND that with a logical vector which represents whether the *preceding* element *is* a group element, thus producing a logical vector which represents only the non-group elements that follow a group. You can then use that to index the original vector to get the result.

Looking at your updated question, it now appears that you want to select only the rows where `Dialled_nbr` is `NA` and where the previous row did *not* have an `NA` in `Dialled_nbr`. You can accomplish that with this:

```
df <- data.frame(
    Dialled_nbr=c(111,111,111,NA,NA,222,222,222,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
    Ringing_nbr=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,456,456,NA),
    Phone_state=c('','','','Active','Active','','','','Active','Active','','','','Active'),
    duration=c('','','','60','0','','','','90','0','','','','100')
);
df[is.na(df$Dialled_nbr) & !c(F,is.na(df$Dialled_nbr[1:(length(df$Dialled_nbr)-1)])),];
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`data.table_1.9.5`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[!is.na(shift(Dialled_nbr)) & is.na(Dialled_nbr)]
#    Dialled_nbr Ringing_nbr Phone_state duration
#1:          NA          NA      Active       60
#2:          NA          NA      Active       90
```